# how to return image binary using multipart/form-data encoding in django

Tags: python, jquery, django, api, file-upload

---

I edited my code on this question based on comments of @dirkgroten, Thanks!

---

In my web site, a submitted image is sent to Django view.

In Django, the image is processed for reducing the size and returned using JsonResponse.

What I want to do is to return the data(binary image) as 'multipart/form-data'format.

Previously my code can upload original photo.
Now I'm adding the size reducing function.
My previous code already works well with the data, multipart/form-date format from html. So I want to keep using the previous code and just add the size reducing function.

**How Can I return the data as 'multipart/form-data' in django view?**

Here is code.

view.py

```py
@login_required
@user_passes_test(customer_check)
def receipt_reduce_size(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
        from io import BytesIO
        from PIL import Image as pil
        import base64
        import sys
        # get image file
        imageFile = request.FILES.get("file")
        input_file = BytesIO(imageFile.read()) # as binary

        # size reducing process below
        img = pil.open(input_file)
        image_file = BytesIO()
        img.save(image_file, format="jpeg", quality=80, optimize=True) # reduced file is saved to 'image_file'
        contents = image_file.getvalue() # the binary value of image_file is save to contents
        encoded = base64.b64encode(contents) # the binary is encoded with base64
        data = encoded.decode('ascii') # and decoded with ascii, so it's now string
        
        return JsonResponse({'status':'success', 'data':data}) 
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'fail'})
```

site.html

In the code, var file(multipart/form-data) is what I used. I want to return the same data format with the file from receipt_reduce_size function of view.py.

```html
<form id="register-submit-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="doctor-info-input form-group mdd-event-wrapper">
        <label for="image" class="control-label">please upload image</label>

        <img src="{% static 'img/event/receipt_example.png' %}" style="width: 80%;margin-top: 20px;">

        <input id="image" name="image" type="file" >
        <input type="hidden" id="image_url" name="image_url">
    </div>

    <button class="btn" type="submit" style="width: 100%;margin-top:20px;">image submit</button>
</form>


<script>
$('#register-submit-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var files = $('#image')[0].files;
        var file = files[0];    // This 'file' is what I used.
        if(!file){
            return alert("please submit again!");
        }
        // image submit start
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'event:s3_direct_upload' %}?file_name=" + file.name + '&file_type=' + file.type,  
            //this api return file path and s3 authorization key
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                var response = data;
                var postData = new FormData();
                for(key in response.data.fields){
                    postData.append(key, response.data.fields[key]);
                }
                var image_new_name = response.image_new_name;
                var postDataUnreduced = new FormData();
                postDataUnreduced.append('file', file);
                postDataUnreduced.append('image_new_name', image_new_name);
                // reduce image file size
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'event::image_reduce_size' %}",
                    type: 'POST',
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    data: postDataUnreduced,
                    success: function(data) {
                        postData.append('file', data);
                        // upload image file
                        $.ajax({
                            url: response.data.url, // this is https://my-site-staticfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/ So, AWS S3 api.
                            type: 'POST',
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            data: postData,
                            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                            },
                            complete: function() {
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('error')
                    }
                })
            },
            complete: function() {
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

When I run my code, what I got in my web are these.

[image in my web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKRy1.png)

[when I click the image link, black.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwGhV.png)

I'm using Django 1.11(not 1.1, sorry for confusing!), Python3.6.7, jQuery and ajax for request and get the response.

Comment: Are you sure about `Django 1.1`? So you are working on a legacy system? Does that mean you are on `Python 2.x` as well?

Comment: @Ralf, I'm using Django 1.1 and Python 3.6.7. Thanks you for commenting!

Comment: I mean is it not `Django 2.1` maybe? `1.1` is really, really old and not supported anymore... thats why I'm asking

Comment: I understand.. But my company using Django 1.1.. we will update it maybe later. sad story

Comment: That's not possible. Django 1.1 doesn't work with python 3.6

Comment: You can't include a binary file inside JSON.

Comment: please see this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django) 
They said Django 1.11 support Python 3.6

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes, so I decoded the data using ascii format. So 'Data' in view.py is str type.

Comment: @mappy Django 1.1 isn't the same as Django 1.11.

Comment: still don't understand what's the problem. You get an error? your javascript doesn't work? Something else? If you're returning one json string, why do you need the response to be multipart?

Comment: @dirkgroten oh... I'm really sorry. I'm usind Django 1.11. That's my poor mistake.

Comment: @dirkgroten Because my previous code use image from html form and passed it to boto3(for saving to aws s3). And I'm doing add function that reduce the image size. I want to return the reduced image binary and give it to boto3 as it was. 
When I just use the code above, uploaded image is not working(which mean I can't see the image in the web site.)

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation..! Thanks you for precious commenting. It really helps me.

Comment: I don't understand, your ajax code first makes a GET request to some view with url 's3_direct_upload'. Which view is that? Then it posts the actual file in the form to the view `receipt_reduce_size` you're showing here, right? The image should be the encoded base64 string in your json, you're not showing the javascript to process that and how you display it on your page. So it's difficult to tell why it's not shown.

Comment: @dirkgroten oh I see now. That's how I supposed to upload the question. I'll edit it based on what you said.

Comment: If possible, upgrade to Django2.2 and python3.7, then go ahead.

Comment: @WaketZheng I think it takes some time to upgrade. Later, I'll do that. Thanks for your comment !